# Number guessing game with leaderboard

Tags: python, numbers, leaderboard

I can code in python with confidence of what I know but I would like to extend what I can do. I had the idea of making a very basic number guessing game and adding some cool things to it such as a leader board to show who got the number in the smallest amount of guesses. However I do not know how to approach adding a leader board to my code.

Help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is very broad and will likely get closed. Please provide specific code and and a specific question where exactly you are stuck codewise.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a leaderboard implies (at least):
 - getting the name of the current player (a simple `input` do the job)
 - saving the  scores> mapping, for this, you can look at `pickle` lib, `json` lib or even some database lib like `py-sqlite3` depending on how you want the data to be stored...

That's just ideas that came to me but i can be a good starting point i guess.